# How to find the correct spatial scale in landscape ecology?

Tags: r, data-mining, spatial, scales, ecology

I am currently studying the effect of organic farming on honeybee colonies. I have calculated the percentage of organic land in several buffer areas around the hives (from 100m to 3000m in 100m steps) and I would like to study how an increase in this percentage changes honeybee performance. Unfortunately we do not know much about the foraging behavior of bees, but we know that they forage at variable scales, depending e.g. on the flower availability. I don't know how to select an appropriate scale.

I have seen that other authors compared via AIC linear models that differed only in the scale of the (explanatory) landscape variable but contained the same response variable. A colleague recommended me to plot the Pearson correlation coefficients of the relation between the response variable and the percentage of organic farming at different scales. From this I should identify a turning point, which would then be the optimal scale.

In some cases I did not really find a turning point within the regarded range of scales, but rather an increase of the correlation coefficient with increasing buffer area. (I do not want to look at larger scales because (i) if the scale is very large the difference in the percentage of organic farming between different hives is small (ii) the hives are not too far from each other, at very large scales there will be a large overlap of buffers from different hives (iii) I regard as unlikely that fields that far from the hive have a strong effect on the colony development.)

Both approaches appear to me like a bit of data mining, as we search a scale where the effect is the largest, based on the correlation without correcting p-values via post-hoc tests.

I tried to see at which scale I have the nicest gradient of organic farming, but this is very subjective and I do not really know which to choose under this aspect, as the percentage of buffers that contain some organic farming increases with a larger buffer area, but the maximum percentage of organic land decreases.

Sorry for this long text. I hope to get some suggestions. ☺ Best, bee guy

Comment: Great question. Part of the answer is easy: ignore your colleague's suggestion.  Don't look at correlation coefficients.  They just aren't relevant or useful in this instance.  Indeed, we should expect that approach (of plotting them as a function of scale) to produce highly biased (that is, wrong) results.

Comment: @whuber: How would you approach this e.g. choosing the scale merely based on the histogram of the organic farming (explanatory variable) within a range that appears reasonable (looking at the literature) or maybe do something more advanced, some kind of machine learning approach that separates training data from test data?